# How to rotate individual SVG elements with jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a SVG with repeated rectangle shapes. On scroll, each rectangle should individually rotate.
The problem I'm having is that the entire SVG block rotates, and not individually.

Is it possible to target the script to treat each rectangle as an individual element to rotate?

Here is my: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24afjmxd/)

Here is a rotation solution I found somewhere, but it affects the entire SVG:

```
$(function() {

  var sdegree = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

  sdegree ++ ;
  sdegree = sdegree + 2 ;
  var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
  $("rect").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
  });

});
```

Comment: If you care about this running in Firefox at all, see this very annoying bug (and good luck): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=612118

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rectangles are all rotating around the origin of the page (the top left).  If you want them to rotate about their own centres, then you will need to include a `transform-origin` in your CSS rule.

```js
$(function() {

  var sdegree = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    sdegree ++ ;
    sdegree = sdegree + 2 ;
    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
    $("rect").css({
      "-webkit-transform" : srotate,
      "transform" : srotate,
      "-webkit-transform-origin" : "50% 50%",
      "transform-origin" : "50% 50%"
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg width="400" height="1900">
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="200" height="200" fill="red"/>
  <rect x="100" y="400" width="200" height="200" fill="orange"/>
  <rect x="100" y="700" width="200" height="200" fill="yellow"/>
  <rect x="100" y="1000" width="200" height="200" fill="green"/>
  <rect x="100" y="1300" width="200" height="200" fill="blue"/>
  <rect x="100" y="1600" width="200" height="200" fill="violet"/>
</svg>
```