# Rotate SVG using pure JS no CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

Is there any way to rotate a SVG element using pure Javascript/Jquery without using CSS3 `transfrom` .

Actually i'm trying to animate SVG using { `transform: rotate(45deg)}` and **its working fine on Chrome and Mozilla** but, on IE `transform:rotate(90deg)` , `-ms-transfrom:rotate(90deg)` dosen;t seems to be working with SVG element.

`transform:rotate(90deg)` is rotating normal images but, fails to rotate SVG element in IE (IE11).

So, i'm searching for some alternate using JS .

Found this **jqueryrotate.com** plugin but, this seems to be using CSS3 animations for rotating and again dosen't work with IE.

Find this question relevant to problem : [How to rotate individual SVG elements with jQuery/Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214887/how-to-rotate-individual-svg-elements-with-jquery-javascript) but, this is setting css properties using JS $().css({}).

i need to find pure js way no CSS3, as CSS3 transitions are not working on IE with SVG.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate individual SVG elements with jQuery/Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214887/how-to-rotate-individual-svg-elements-with-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to rotate an entire SVG, the best would be to wrap it and rotate the wrapper, so IE will do the transform and you will avoid the buggy behavior of Firefox with SVG + transform.

if you do not want to use css (via stylesheet or via javascript), then you will have to use canvas i guess.

```css
.IeRotateSvg {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: rotate 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="IeRotateSvg">
  <svg version="1.0" width="600" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Grad1" x1="41.1948738" y1="616.477173" x2="118.931351" y2="527.555115" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(4.556763,0,0,-4.315033,37.49756,2758.519)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bb0000" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#5f0000" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="Grad2" x1="530.809509" y1="486.631012" x2="174.805481" y2="211.22995" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.960006,0,0,0.960006,11.68071,9.787565)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9a0000" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f22803" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="Grad3" x1="187.873566" y1="224.598923" x2="581.837463" y2="483.100006" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.960006,0,0,0.960006,11.68071,9.787558)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ec6c60" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d11412" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="Grad4" x1="250.398453" y1="101.536331" x2="412.094299" y2="264.54187" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.960006,0,0,0.960006,11.68071,9.787565)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffd9d9" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ff2727" />
      </linearGradient>
      <radialGradient id="Grad5" cx="295.471252" cy="186.096344" r="179.550003" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.14292e-8,1.531256,-0.876504,-2.165967e-5,462.7486,-245.0023)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffffff" />
        <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#ffffff" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d5d5d5" />
      </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <path d="M 287.0439 30.68461 C 287.0439 30.68461 26.88238 457.8871 26.88238 457.8871 C 21.89034 466.0472 21.89034 476.1272 26.88238 484.2873 C 31.77841 492.3513 40.99446 497.4394 50.97852 497.4394 L 571.3016 497.4394 C 581.1896 497.4394 590.4057 492.3513 595.3977 484.2873 C 600.2937 476.1272 600.2937 466.0472 595.3977 457.8871 L 335.2362 30.68461 C 330.2442 22.52457 321.0281 17.43654 311.14 17.43654 C 301.252 17.43654 292.0359 22.52457 287.0439 30.68461 z "
    style="fill-opacity:0.178571;" />
    <path d="M 275.5863 23.03565 C 275.5863 23.03565 15.42473 450.2381 15.42473 450.2381 C 10.4327 458.3982 10.4327 468.4783 15.42473 476.6383 C 20.32076 484.7024 29.53681 489.7904 39.52087 489.7904 L 559.8439 489.7904 C 569.732 489.7904 578.948 484.7024 583.9401 476.6383 C 588.8361 468.4783 588.8361 458.3982 583.9401 450.2381 L 323.7785 23.03565 C 318.7865 14.8756 309.5705 9.787568 299.6824 9.787568 C 289.7943 9.787568 280.5783 14.8756 275.5863 23.03565 z "
    style="fill:url(#Grad1);" />
    <path d="M 299.6824 31.7717 C 298.0504 31.7717 296.5144 32.6357 295.6504 33.97971 L 165.5696 247.581 L 35.48885 461.1822 C 34.62484 462.5262 34.62484 464.2542 35.48885 465.5982 C 36.35285 466.9422 37.88886 467.8062 39.52087 467.8062 L 559.8439 467.8062 C 561.4759 467.8062 563.0119 466.9422 563.876 465.5982 C 564.74 464.2542 564.74 462.5262 563.876 461.1822 L 303.7144 33.97971 C 302.8504 32.6357 301.3144 31.7717 299.6824 31.7717 z "
    style="fill:url(#Grad2);" />
    <path d="M 299.6464 31.7717 C 298.0144 31.7717 296.4783 32.6357 295.6143 33.97971 L 165.5336 247.581 L 35.45283 461.1822 C 34.58882 462.5262 34.58882 464.2542 35.45283 465.5982 C 36.31683 466.9422 37.85284 467.8062 39.48485 467.8062 L 559.8079 467.8062 C 561.4399 467.8062 562.9759 466.9422 563.8399 465.5982 C 564.7039 464.2542 564.7039 462.5262 563.8399 461.1822 L 303.6784 33.97971 C 302.8144 32.6357 301.2784 31.7717 299.6464 31.7717 z "
    style="fill:none;stroke:url(#Grad3);stroke-width:11.52;stroke-linejoin:round;" />
    <path d="M 299.7514 39.46512 C 298.2057 39.54152 296.7649 40.40413 295.9414 41.68514 L 165.8606 255.2864 L 147.7405 285.0466 C 191.8747 311.5396 243.5133 326.8068 298.7014 326.8068 C 354.6732 326.8068 407.0086 311.1293 451.5523 283.9366 L 304.0114 41.68514 C 303.1474 40.34112 301.6234 39.46512 299.9914 39.46512 C 299.9149 39.46512 299.8274 39.46136 299.7514 39.46512 z "
    style="fill:url(#Grad4);stroke-width:10;stroke-linejoin:round;" />
    <path d="M 286.4344 145.7244 L 129.2814 403.678 C 126.5934 408.1901 126.5934 413.7581 129.2814 418.1741 C 131.9695 422.6861 137.0575 425.4702 142.5295 425.4702 L 456.7395 425.4702 C 462.2115 425.4702 467.2996 422.6861 469.9876 418.1741 C 472.6756 413.6621 472.6756 408.1901 469.9876 403.678 L 312.9306 145.7244 C 310.2426 141.2124 305.1545 138.4284 299.6825 138.4284 C 294.2105 138.4284 289.1224 141.2124 286.4344 145.7244 z "
    style="fill:url(#Grad5);" />
    <path d="M 291.3968 416.3174 C 282.3931 412.0051 275.5362 401.6362 275.5362 392.3333 C 275.5362 375.0116 293.6366 361.9634 310.762 366.9398 C 322.3151 370.2971 330.1674 380.7229 330.0712 392.5774 C 329.9891 402.6474 325.6306 410.0656 316.7341 415.2773 C 309.9242 419.2665 298.5306 419.7341 291.3968 416.3174 z M 293.4432 347.9194 C 292.3177 347.3009 289.6669 345.1473 287.5529 343.1337 C 280.1664 336.0983 280.1756 336.1602 275.3607 260.8815 C 271.0805 193.9641 271.0451 192.9243 272.8817 188.1175 C 277.0134 177.3028 286.2196 172.5672 301.5485 173.3714 C 311.2922 173.8827 318.7963 177.3045 323.674 183.4607 C 327.8404 188.719 328.7462 191.6916 328.7424 200.0923 C 328.7383 209.2211 322.9068 321.1701 322.0779 328.0305 C 320.9926 337.0156 315.7466 344.3072 308.0575 347.5177 C 303.6637 349.3525 296.4136 349.5518 293.4432 347.9194 z "
    />
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: @atulquest93 You need to set the coordonates of the rotating point in transform-origin: https://jsfiddle.net/92n9s9zs/4/ lokks average like 123px 108px here

Answer (score 1):

You can set attribute `transform` on the svg element you want to rotate. For example, if you want to rotate element with `id='el'`, you can do:

```
document.getElementById('el').setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(90)');
```

Comment: Yes,  this is working fine with Chrome and Mozilla as I've mentioned but, not working with IE. So, for IE i need to figure out solution.

Comment: With SVG element ? `transfrom:rotate(45deg)` is working with normal images but, not able to rotate SVG element. But, its working with Chrome and mozilla.

Comment: Of course. Did you try? This is setting pure atribute, it doesn't have anything to do with CSS